# getting td value per tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code in the following style :

```
<tr id="201461">
      <td id="0A" style="cursor:pointer" onClick = "ProcessTextBoxClick()" value="Feb 23 2008">Feb 23 2008</td>
      <td id="0B" style="cursor:pointer" onClick = "ProcessTextBoxClick()" value="Feb 25 2008">Feb 25 2008</td>
      <td id="0C" style="cursor:pointer" onClick = "ProcessTextBoxClick()" value="Feb 28 2008">Feb 28 2008</td></tr><tr id="201460">
       <td id="1A" style="cursor:pointer" onClick = "ProcessTextBoxClick()" value="47">47</td></tr>
```

I have some JQuery where I am getting the id of each row, and now I want to get each value in each td for each row.  How do I do this?

```
 var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl-1");

    var numRows = tbl.rows.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {

        var ID = tbl.rows[i].id;
```

Comment: that's not jQuery

Comment: Agreed with @KARASZI - there's no JQuery code in there. Javascript, yes; JQuery, no.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that HTML ID attributes are not allowed to be numeric values or start with a digit; it's invalid HTML. See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/valid-characters-html-id-attribute/

Comment: **Off-topic**, but note that [`td` doesn't have a `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element), so that HTML is invalid. You might look at [`data-` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: @Spudley: In HTML 4.01, [`id` values could not *start* with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), it's true. As of HTML5, an [`id` can have anything you want](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) as long as it doesn't have spaces. To make things worse, there's a *third* set of slightly-different rules [for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Yes, really. ;-) (I tend to stick to the CSS rules, they're the most restrictive and therefore most broadly-useful.)

Comment: @T.J. - thanks for the update. Even if it's allowed in some contexts, I'd still always avoid having numerical IDs, for my own sanity if for no other reason ;-)

Comment: I don't see this question being off-topic at all. It is completely relevant and applicable, as it was for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in jQuery:

```
$("table#tbl-1 tr").each(function( i ) {
  $("td", this).each(function( j ) {
    console.log("".concat("row: ", i, ", col: ", j, ", value: ", $(this).text()));
  });
});
```

You can check it in work here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kWNh/

Answer (score 18):

Your code does not look like jQuery. Are you sure you aren't using the term jQuery as a synonym to JavaScript? :) If that is the case, I suggest you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript) as well; it will make things a lot more clear for you.

**Anyway, here goes JavaScript:**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl-1");
var numRows = tbl.rows.length;

for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
    var ID = tbl.rows[i].id;
    var cells = tbl.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var ic=0,it=cells.length;ic<it;ic++) {
        // alert the table cell contents
        // you probably do not want to do this, but let's just make
        // it SUPER-obvious  that it works :)
        alert(cells[ic].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

**Alternatively, if you really use jQuery:**

```
var table = $('#tbl-1').
var rowIds = [];
var cells = [];
$('tr', table).each(function() {
    rowIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    $('td', $(this)).each(function() {
        cells.push($(this).html());
    });
});
// you now have all row ids stores in the array 'rowIds'
// and have all the cell contents stored in 'cells'
```

Comment: This is the code I was looking for...but is it possible to specify each td so that I can assign each different td value to a different variable? td id 0A for example might be a start date, 1A might be an integer etc

Comment: @user you should be ready to go with my example: this is not the place if you looking for click-and-go JavaScript. Consider the example and try to come up with your own solution. That way you will learn a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get each value in each td for each row

Do you want the value of the `value` attribute, the HTML, or the HTML stripped of markup? The various answers so far have mostly gone with "the HTML", at least one went with "the HTML stripped of markup", but none (so far) has gone with "the value of the `value` attribute". So:

Using jQuery:

```
var valuesByRowID = {};
$("#tbl-1 tr").each(function() {
    valuesByRowID[this.id] = $(this).find("> td").map(function() {
        // Option 1: Getting the value of the `value` attribute:
        return this.getAttribute("value"); // or return $(this).attr("value");

        // Option 2: Getting the HTML of the `td`:
        return this.innerHTML;

        // Option 3: Getting the HTML of the `td` with markup stripped:
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
});
```

The end result is an object with properties for each row, with the property name being the row's `id` value, and the property value being an array of the `td` information.

So for instance, to get the array for row `201461`, you can do this:

```
var data = valuesByRowID["201461"]; // Note that property names are strings
var index;
for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
    alert(data[index]);
}
```

The above uses:

- [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) to find the rows in the table.
- [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) (followed by `get`) to build the array of values.
- A simple JavaScript object to hold the result. JavaScript objects are, at heart, maps (aka dictionaries, aka associative arrays, aka name/value pair collections).

---

**Off-topic**:

- As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the HTML you've listed there is "invalid" in W3C terminology, [`td` elements don't have a `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). You might consider using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) instead.
- As Spudley pointed out in a comment on the question, those `id` values are likely to cause you trouble. Recommend *not* having `id` values that start with a digit. Although [valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), they're [not valid in earlier versions of HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [not valid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, if you're using CSS, I would strongly advise sticking to the CSS rules. (In your case, it's really easy: Just put an `d` on the front of them or seomthing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
$("td","#tbl-1").each(function(){
//access the value as
 $(this).html()

});
```

Comment: Your selector argument is invalid.

Comment: Clarifying @Jason's point: The variant of the `$()` function you're using requires that the `context` argument be a DOM element, Document, or jQuery instance (not a String): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: I believe there is nothing wrong with my selector or code as is demonstrated by http://jsfiddle.net/nikhil/Cy6hR/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over all `<td>`

```
$('#tbl-1 td').each(function() {
  // do stuff for each td in here...
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

**NOTE:** This is jQuery whereas your example is native JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using there is not jQuery, if you are using jQuery you can use `.html();` to retrieve the value.

Here is your code with jQuery:

```
$('#tbl-1 td').each(function(){

    var ID    = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).html();

});
```